# Создать словарь "календарь" в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь реализовать генератор словаря, который будет организован, как календарь, т.е. 12 месяцев, в которых 31 день, и в каждом дне есть список (в который будут складываться другие списки).

Вот мой код:

```
year = {}
monthes = ['jan', 'feb', 'mrt', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'avg', 'spt', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec']
days = {}

for elem in range(1, 32):
    days[elem] = dict()

for elem in monthes:
    year[elem] = days

print(year)
```

Comment: @smilemakc, лучше всё-таки показать код. На этом ресурсе не делают работу за других, здесь помогают тем, кто что-то делает сам, но где-то застрял. И поишите подробнее, что именно вы пытаетесь получить на выходе, из вопрося не совсем понятно, что должен выдавать генератор - дни, месяцы, генераторы дней в месяце?

Comment: Year={}
monthes=['jan', 'feb', 'mrt', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'avg', 'spt', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec']
days={}
for elem in range(1,32):
    days[elem]=dict()

for elem in monthes:
    Year[elem]=days

print(Year)

Comment: Зачем словарь нужен? Можно посмотреть на calendar, datetime модули, может они предоставляют нужную функциональность, вместо словаря.

Comment: @jfs,
Пишу парсер сайта с новостями. Для начала, мне нужно создать "базу" всех записей за несколько лет, где в словаре "день" будет лежать запись, где ключ "время": (ссылка, картинка и текст) и понеобходимости вытаскивать записи из архива. Как то так.
Библиотеки это хорошо, но хочется пробовать свои реализации, дабы развивать познания в языке

Comment: Для даты/времени в таком сценарии можно использовать стандартные datetime.date, datetime.datetime классы (в UTC или c прикриплёнными timezone, чтобы не было неоднозначностей) -- реализовывать Грегорианский календарь не очень интересно. Я бы не стал акцент на *словаре* делать, какую структруру данных использовать внутри скрипта для создания, обновления базы данных, зависит что за библиотеки используются для извлечения инфы со сайта (HTMLParser, BeautifulSoup) и какими библиотеки используются для сохранения в базу (sqlite3). Можно использовать или посмотреть как реализован scrapy, который полну

Comment: цепочку по заходу по ссылками, парсинга, фильтрации и сохранения демонстрирует.

Answer (score 3):

В стандартной библиотеке python есть модуль calendar, который прекрасно справляется с этой задачей.

Answer (score 1):

```
import calendar

class Cl(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.update({}.fromkeys(calendar.month_name[1:]))
        d = tuple(range(1, 32))
        for m in self:
            self[m] = {}.fromkeys(d, [[m]])

    def __missing__(self, key: (int, int)):
        return self[calendar.month_name[key[0]]][key[1]]

c = Cl()

print(c)
print(c[5, 6][0][0])
```

out:

```
{'September': {1: [['September']], 2: [['September']], ...}, 'February': {1: [['February']], 2: [['February']], ...}, ...}
May
```